# Why is destructor invoked when assigning to std::any object

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I have the code below where I see an unexpected invoke of the destructor when assigning to a std::any object. The invoking of the destructor disappears when the copy constructor is explicitly declared and implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

struct MyStruct {
    int mx;

    MyStruct(int x) : mx{x} {
        std::cout << "MyStruct(" << x << ")" << std::endl;
    }

//     MyStruct(const MyStruct& other) {
//         std::cout << "Copy constructor (" << other.mx << ")" << std::endl;
//         mx = other.mx;
//     }
//
//    MyStruct& operator=(const MyStruct& other) {
//        std::cout << "Copy assignment (" << other.mx << ")" << std::endl;
//        mx = other.mx;
//        return *this;
//    }
//
//    MyStruct(MyStruct&& other) {
//        std::cout << "Move constructor (" << other.mx << ")" << std::endl;
//        mx = other.mx;
//    }
//
//    MyStruct& operator=(MyStruct&& other) {
//        std::cout << "Move assignment (" << other.mx << ")" << std::endl;
//        mx = other.mx;
//        return *this;
//    }

    ~MyStruct()
    {
        std::cout << "~MyStruct(" << mx << ")" << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct n1{35};
    MyStruct n2{47};
    std::cout << "MyStruct objects were created\n" << std::endl;

    std::any a = n1;
    std::cout << "n1 assigned to a\n"<< std::endl;

    a = n2;
    std::cout << "n2 assigned to a\n"<< std::endl;

    std::cout << "MyStruct objects from beginning and mystruct object held by a are going to be destructed\n"<< std::endl;
}
```

I see the following output for this code:

```
MyStruct(35)
MyStruct(47)
MyStruct objects were created

n1 assigned to a

~MyStruct(35)
~MyStruct(47)
n2 assigned to a


MyStruct objects from the beginning and the mystruct object held by a are going to be destructed

~MyStruct(47)
~MyStruct(47)
~MyStruct(35)
```

In the code above, according to the standards, since I declared a constructor and destructor, the copy constructor and copy assignment are defaulted by the compiler. What I expect to see in order:

1. As expected: I expect to see the invocation of the two constructors for the two objects `n1` and `n2` that I create.
2. As expected: I assign `n1` to `a` and I was expecting the copy constructor to be invoked, which I will not be able to see since it is defaulted by the compiler.
3. As expected: I am assigning `n2` to `a`, so I expect the copy constructor to be invoked again and the destructor for the object contained in a previously with value `mx` 35. I would expect the call to be in reverse order, so first destruct then copy construct. We can also clearly see a destructor invoked for an object with value `mx` 47 when assigning `n2` to `a`. I am not expecting to see this unless behind the screens my `n2` object is first copied into some type of temporary object first.
4. As expected: I expect the object contained in `a` and the 2 objects `n1` and `n2` I created to be destructed in reverse order of creation because they go out of scope.

What confuses me, even more, is that this behavior changes when I self-implement the other special member functions. Whether you uncomment just the copy constructor or the other special member functions, the output `~MyStruct(47)` at the moment of assigning `n2` to `a` disappears. This is the output if at least the copy constructor is uncommented from the code above:

```
MyStruct(35)
MyStruct(47)
MyStruct objects were created

Copy constructor (35)
n1 assigned to a

Copy constructor (47)
~MyStruct(35)
n2 assigned to a

MyStruct objects from the beginning and the mystruct object held by a are going to be destructed

~MyStruct(47)
~MyStruct(47)
~MyStruct(35)
```

So my concrete questions are the following:

1. Why is the destructor invoked for an object with `mx` 47 in the first situation?
2. Why is the destructor invoked after the copy constructor when assigning `n2` and not before?
3. Why does the destructor for the object with `mx` value 47 suddenly stop being invoked when at least the copy constructor is added?

The codes above have been compiled with g++, Microsoft, and Clang compilers for both C++17 and C++20 standards.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment operator of `any` is [specified to do](https://eel.is/c++draft/any#assign-10):

> *Effects*: Constructs an object `tmp` of type `any` that contains an object of type `VT` direct-initialized with `std​::​forward<T>(rhs)`, and `tmp.swap(*this)`. No effects if an exception is thrown.

What libstdc++ does is that `any = n2;` evaluates as `any = std::any(n2);`. That temporary `any` is destroyed at the end of the statement, which is where your unexpected destructor print comes from.

Now, `any` has an optimization: it doesn't *always* allocate the object that it holds onto. If the type is sufficiently small and is no-throw move constructible, the object will be constructed inplace within the `any`, saving the allocation. Initially, your type satisfied that requirement. However, when you added your move constructor explicitly, it wasn't `noexcept`, so the `any` has to allocate. The result of this allocation, though, is that move-assigning an `any` can just take over the right-hand-side's pointer without having to move the object and destroy the original. So you don't get the destructor in that case (or the move).

But if you add `noexcept`, then you'll see both the destructor and the move.

Comment: In the original situation actually the move constructor and move assignment are not declared according to the standards right? If you explicitly declare the constructor and destructor copy constructor and copy assignment are defaulted, but the move constructor and move assignment should be not declared.

Comment: @MasterMind No, you still had defaulted move operations.